# How to replace a delimiter between two other delimiters?

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a string like the one below:

```
engineer,doctor,"987,345,123",engineer
```

I wanted to change it to below in Unix:

```
engineer,doctor,"987345123",engineer
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing all commas from the 3rd field from each CSV record in the input, using a `gsub()` operation using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  The input data set is assumed to be header-less.

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put '$3 = gsub($3, ",", "")' file
engineer,doctor,987345123,engineer
```

To retain the original quotes even though they are no longer needed:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N --quote-original put '$3 = gsub($3, ",", "")' file
engineer,doctor,"987345123",engineer
```